# how to crate BMI Calculator in shopify?

Tags: javascript, forms, shopify, calculator

```
<style>
form {
  text-align: center;
}

</style>
<title>
      Simple BMI Calculator
    </title>
    <script src="2-bmi.js"></script>
  

    <form onsubmit="return calcBMI();"> 
      מחשבון BMI:
      <label>
<br>
        <input type="radio" id="bmi-metric" name="bmi-measure" onchange="measureBMI()" checked=""> מטרי
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="bmi-imperial" name="bmi-measure" onchange="measureBMI()"> אימפריאל
      </label>
      <br><br>

      משקל:
      <input id="bmi-weight" type="number" min="1" max="635" required=""> 
      <span id="bmi-weight-unit">ק"ג</span>
      <br><br>

      גובה:
      <input id="bmi-height" type="number" min="54" max="272" required="">
      <span id="bmi-height-unit">ס"מ</span>
      <br><br>

      <input class="btn btn-color-primary btn-style-default btn-size-small" style="text-align" :center="" type="submit" value="חישוב BMI">
      <div id="bmi-results"></div>
    </form>
```

I have a website that I maintain on health and nutrition. And it's important for me to have a weight calculation that will give an answer after pressing a button. Automatic calculation answer and not sentences.

this code I use but it didn't work. why and how I fix it? and I need this in Shopify...
ty.

Comment: what is error and what is not working ?

Comment: When I press the button it refreshes my page and does not bring calculation results. I put this code on the main page in shopify. I put that code in there.

Comment: What is the code that is running? (Specifically, what does the `calcBMI()` function that you're calling do?)